# Unexpected Python variable scope using Walrus Operator := assignment expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

I found the variable scope of the following code to be very unexpected... (coming from other languages where the scope of the `scope_var` variable would only exist for the span of the IF):

```
if scope_var := 'exists after IF':
    pass
print(scope_var)
```

What will be printed?

Comment: Python doesn't have block scope. This isn't anything to do with assignment expressions themselves

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Outputs: **exists after IF**

so the variable `scope_var` now exists outside / past the IF statement.

This was very strange to me, so I thought I post this Q/A for others coming from other languages to learn from. (I Googled quite a few articles, and nothing like this answer came up, so I hope this helps people like myself.)

...

Apparently it's not just the Walrus := assignment expression. It happens with a regular FOR statement as well:

```
for i in range(3):     
    pass 
print(i)
```

Outputs: **2**

The variable is available in the surrounding scope.